# Alexander Duality Theorem, a simple version in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is it fair to say that the following generalization of the **Jordan-Brouwer Theorem**, due to J. Leray, is a version of the **Alexander Duality Theorem**?

> *If the two compact sets $K,\tilde{K}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are homeomorphic, then the sets $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus K$ and $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \tilde{K}$ have the same number of connected components.*

Comment: You need additional conditions on your sets (eg compact), else it is false.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks, that was a typo.

Comment: It is indeed a generalization of the separation theorem but not stated in in its true form which involves Chech cohomology and singular homology.

Comment: I would say that it is an *application* of Alexander Duality. But it is not nearly strong enough to be a "version": for that it would have to say something about higher dimensional homology. As stated, it is only about zero dimensional homology, whose rank equals the number of path components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

The answer was given in the comments by Moishe Kohan and Lee Mosher.

Certainly Alexander Duality is needed in a form covering *arbitrary compact subsets* of $\mathbb R^n$. This involves Čech cohomology $\check{H}^*$ and states that for any compact $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ there exists an isomorphism
$$\tilde{H}_q(\mathbb R^n \setminus K) \approx \check{H}^{n-q-1}(K).$$
Here $\tilde{H}_*$ denotes reduced singular homology.
If $K, K'$ are homeomorphic, this implies $\tilde{H}_0(\mathbb R^n \setminus K) \approx \check{H}^{n-1}(K) \approx \check{H}^{n-1}(K') \approx \tilde{H}_0(\mathbb R^n \setminus K')$. In particular both complements must have the same number of path components. Since both complements are open in $\mathbb R^n$, they are locally path connected whence components and path components agree.

However, Alexander duality is much stronger than your generalization of the Jordan-Brouwer Theorem.